# clojure spec - validating contents of maps

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I want to create a clojure spec for a map that has rules about the presence of particular keys.

The map must have a `:type` and can have either `:default` or `:value` but not both.  I tried:

```
(s/def ::propertyDef
  (s/keys :req [::type (s/or ::default ::value) ] :opt [::description ::required]))
```

but I got

```
CompilerException java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed:
    spec/or expects k1 p1 k2 p2..., where ks are keywords
    (c/and (even? (count key-pred-forms)) (every? keyword? keys)),
    compiling:(C:\Users\MartinRoberts\AppData\Local\Temp\form-init4830956164341520551.clj:1:22)
```

but the `or` gave me an error as it is in the wrong format.  I have to admit to not really understanding in the documentation for `s/or`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First:  you are using `s/or` to specify either a `::default` or a `::value` in your list of required keys.  `s/or` requires `:label spec` pairs, and you are giving only the specs themselves, which is the cause of the error.

To solve, simply use `or` instead:

```
(s/def ::propertyDef (s/keys :req [::type (or ::default ::value)]
                             :opt [::description ::required]))
```

This allows both `::default` and `::value` to be present in the map, but this is almost always okay.  The code which actually uses the map can simply check for the presence of `::value` and use that, and if it's not there, then use `::default` (or whatever your logic happens to be).  This is usually done as such:

```
(let [myvalue (or (::value mymap) (::default mymap))] ...)
```

There could be thousands of keys in the map, and it would not affect your ability to extract the keys you need.  This is why spec does not provide a built-in way to specify keys that should not be in the map, only ways to specify which keys *should* be present (namely, `:req` and `:req-un` in `s/keys`).  Think of how most http servers work: you can give them nonsensical header keys and values, but they don't refuse to service the request; they just ignore them and return a response.

So, you likely don't need to enforce that only one or the other be present, but if you must, you can define an exclusive or function:

```
(defn xor
  [p q]
  (and (or p q)
       (not (and p q))))
```

and then add this as an additional predicate on the spec:

```
(s/def ::propertyDef (s/and (s/keys :req [::type (or ::default ::value)]
                                    :opt [::description ::required])
                            #(xor (::default %) (::value %))))

(s/valid? ::propertyDef {::type "type" ::default "default"})
=> true
(s/valid? ::propertyDef {::type "type" ::value "value"})
=> true
(s/valid? ::propertyDef {::type "type" ::default "default" ::value "value"})
=> false
```

Comment: The first part of this is right, but the `xor` part is not. The `or` and `and` "functions" inside `:req` are the only supported symbols that can be used inside `:req`. This might work right now (don't know), but if so that's accidental and may stop working at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification -- I moved the `xor` outside the key spec and into a separate predicate @AlexMiller